# Error in Vue — Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>` arrow-body-style

Tags: vue.js

When adding a Vue.filter globally, the linter swears and I can’t understand how to fix this error:

```
Vue.filter('truncate', (text, length) => {
  return text.length > length ? `${text.slice(0, length - 1)}...` : text;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. You have one statement so just put them in online like

```
Vue.filter('truncate', (text, length) => {return text.length > length ? `${text.slice(0, length - 1)}...` : text;
});
```

or it is more es6,

```
Vue.filter('truncate', (text, length) => (text.length > length ? `${text.slice(0, length - 1)}...:` text;
);
```

more info refer to [link](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style)

for example,

incorrect code

```
/*eslint arrow-body-style: ["error", "as-needed"]*/
/*eslint-env es6*/
let foo = () => {
    return 0;
};
let foo = () => {
    return {
       bar: {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2,
        }
    };
};
```

correct code

```
/*eslint arrow-body-style: ["error", "as-needed"]*/
/*eslint-env es6*/

let foo = () => 0;
let foo = (retv, name) => {
    retv[name] = true;
    return retv;
};
let foo = () => ({
    bar: {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
    }
});
let foo = () => { bar(); };
let foo = () => {};
let foo = () => { /* do nothing */ };
let foo = () => {
    // do nothing.
};
let foo = () => ({ bar: 0 });
```

[source](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I worked after modifying the conditions:

`Vue.filter('truncate', (text, length) => {
  if (text.length > length) return `${text.slice(0, length - 1)}...`;
  return text;
});`